# How to mention elastic search roles serverless.yml

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm working on an **serverless** project with **aws-python3** template.
The **lambda** needs to write to amazon elastic search database.
So how do I mention these thing in **serverless.yml** file in iamroles section.

Answer (score 0):

Build it up [using CloudFormation syntax](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticsearch-domain.html) in the `resources:` section.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example IAM Policy that allows a Lambda function to write to an AWS ElasticSearch database.

I suggest you employ the use of the popular plugin [serverless-pseudo-parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-pseudo-parameters) to fill in the AccountID, Region, etc.

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "es:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-1:987654321098:domain/test-domain/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html